# How can I change substring(s) in an array of strings in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, arrays, objective-c

I have a weird error with decoding `&` sign so its always shown as `&amp;`, so `&&` will be `&amp;&amp;`, `a&b` is shown as `a&amp;b` etc.

I have those weird characters in my array of strings sometimes, so I want to remove them. To be more clear, if I have an array like this:

```
"str1", "a&amp;b", "12345", "d&amp;&amp;emo&amp;"
```

I want to it to be:

```
"str1", "a&b", "12345", "d&&emo&"
```

So all `&amp;` should be changed into just `&`.

This is the code I tried, but it didn't help. Elements are not changing their values:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= self.array-1; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", self.array[i]);
    [self.array[i] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.array[i]);
}
```

I am new to Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSString` instances are immutable, which means you can't change them once they are created. The `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:withString:` method actually returns a new `NSString` instance. You could use `NSMutableString`, or alternatively, you can create a new array containing the replacement strings, e.g.:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *input in self.array)
{
    NSString *replacement = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"];   
    [newArray addObject:replacement];
}

self.array = newArray;
```